# water under sill plate, rotting sheathing

Tags: slab, rot, sill-plate

I have a detached garage of unknown age - the house is from 1935, so probably around then or newer. The garage is built directly on the slab with no curb wall. On one side of the garage, the slab is at grade with some other concrete, so water pools when it rains. Some runs under the sill and some wicks up into the sheathing, which has begun to rot. This has clearly been going on for a while - the previous owner replaced the sill with pressure-treated wood (edit: no, they replaced it with standard 2x4s), patched and sistered a bunch of the studs, and replaced the sheathing (it’s old t&g sheathing with shakes on the rest of the garage, and t1-11 on the side with the rot

I’d like to get a permanent fix here. Some of the things I’ve considered:

1. I’ve read elsewhere about lifting the wall, cutting the bottom of the studs off at around 10”, adding block or pouring a curb, and then putting the sill on top of it. This sounds ideal, but I have a lot of questions about how to lay the block so that it adheres well and doesn’t just wick water up to the sill anyway. If I did this, I think going all around the garage seems like the smart thing to do, and I’d definitely want to
2. I *think* the primary problem at this point is the sheathing wicking water, so I wonder if I can replace the sill 2x4 with 4x4 and then be able to leave more gap from the sheathing to the ground.
3. replace the sheathing with pressure treated wood

1 sounds like the most complete option, since 2 & 3 don’t seem like they’d fix the water entry, just the sheathing rot.

I think my questions are:

- does option 1 seem reasonable? If so, where can I learn more about adding the curb to the slab and attaching the sill plate to the curb?
- with options 2 & 3, is there anything I could add to the system to prevent water entry?
- are there other options I should be considering?
- if I were to hire this out, what kind of contractor should I be looking for?

[image: Side of garage showing rot along the bottom edge of the siding]
[image: inside of garage showing sill plate on slab]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: pictures of the area will help determine a solution.

Comment: thanks @RMDman - I added some pictures and updated some content!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue appears to be the water pooling. What is the slab that abuts the garage? This either needs to slope away from the garage, or have a (well drained) gap added. Pressure-treating only helps so much.

Sheathing shouldn't be down to ground level. You may need to adjust ground level around the slab.

Comment: the slab is just a couple feet of slab, then it meets my property line. At the property line, there's a railroad tie retainer with a fence on top of it. My guess is that the slab was extended by someone tired of dealing with weeds. I'm wondering now if the best option is to replace that slab with gravel, then replace the sill + sheathing (obviously with the sheathing off the ground this time)

Comment: Agreed. Proper drainage _first_, then do the repairs (unless the building is in emmenent danger of collapse.